# Pullbacks and isomorphisms of vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I want to clarify certain details regarding pullbacks of vector bundles. I suspect my question will be equivalent in every possible setting: topological, differentiable and holomorphic vector bundles.

**Setting**

Let $X$ be a manifold and $E$ a vector bundle over $X$. We consider automorphisms of $X$, namely those isomorphisms in the appropriate category (homeomorphisms, diffeomorphisms, biholomorphisms...). Let $g:X\rightarrow X$ be one such automorphism. I can construct the *pullback bundle* by either declaring transition functions from those of $E$
$$
E \equiv \{U_i, \psi_{ij}\} \implies g^*E \equiv \{g^{-1}(U_i), \psi_{ij}\circ g\}
$$
or even more explicitly by
$$
g^*E = \{ (x,e)\in X\times E| g(x)=\pi(e)\}
$$
I already know that there is a commutative diagram involving these bundles
$$\begin{array}
*g^*E & \stackrel{\hat{g}}{\longrightarrow} & E \\
\downarrow{p_1} & & \downarrow{\pi} \\
X & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & X  
\end{array}
$$
and $g(x,e)=e$ covers the automorphism $g$.

**Question**

I want to clarify if it is possible that $g^*E$ is **isomorphic** to the original bundle, meaning there is a commutative diagram as above **covering the identity on X**. I know this is a stronger condition, but as I have $g$ an **automorphism** of $X$, I suspect this could be possible in some situations.

For example, from the classification of line bundles over $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1$, I can use the pullback of a connection and show that the degree/first Chern number is invariant under the action of $g\in SL(2,C)\subset Aut(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1)$, and thus $g^*L\simeq L$ for every line bundle over the projective line.

I am trying to come up with a proof that either implements explicitly an identity-covering-vector-bundle-map or a proof involving Cech cohomology, but I would really prefer the former.

If this is false, I would like to build an explicit counterexample.

Comment: From functoriality of the pullback, I can prove that $(g^{-1})^*g^*E \simeq E$, but that is weaker than what I am trying to prove.

Comment: I think  you extend the diagram to the right using $g^{-1}$ and use the fact that $g^*(g^{-1})^*(E) \cong E$

Comment: I know what you mean, but there's a slight nitpick in doing that: pullback of maps between bundles only works if that map already covers the identity. I can use $id = g^{-1}\circ g$ using the diagram you say, but that wouldn't give me any interaction between $E\simeq g^* (g^{-1})^*E$ and $g^*E$.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. As you said, sometimes the pull backs are isomorphic, sometimes not. Are you asking for examples of the phenomena?

Comment: Dear Mohan, I was not sure that the answer was "*no, in general*". Do you have a simple counterexample at hand?

For instance, my reasoning regarding $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1$ critically depend on the fact that automorphisms preserve orientation and thus the degree of bundle does not change sign. Now I realize that in the $C^\infty$ world I could build an orientation reversing diffeomorphism $g$ that therefore changes the degree implying $g^*E \not\simeq E$.

Comment: In the algebraic context, you can consider the case of a translation on an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3):

It is *usually* the case that if you have a nontrivial automorphism $g : X \to X$ of a complex manifold then $g^* E$ is not isomorphic to $E$. It is easiest to give an example for holomorphic line bundles.

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $E = \mathcal{O}(1,0)$ the sheaf associated to the ``horizontal'' divisor. Then the automorphism $g : X \to X$ swapping the two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ then $g^* \mathcal{O}(1,0) = \mathcal{O}(0,1)$ which are not isomorphic (think about linear equivalences of divisors).

In general, for holomorphic line bundles, it is usually easy to detect when this occurs because $g$ acts quite explicitly on $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ in terms of moving around divisors (e.g. $g$ takes ''horizontal lines'' to ''vertical lines'' in the previous example).

For complex (smooth) line bundles, there is a similar story. The first Chern class $c_1(L) \in H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is a complete invariant so you just need to see how an automorphism acts on $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$. In the previous case, $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2}$ and $g$ swaps the factors of $\mathbb{Z}$ so we see that $g^* E$ and $E$ are not isomorphic as *complex* line bundles.

Finally, for real line bundles, the first Steifel-Whitney class $w_2(L) \in H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is a complete invariant so you just need to see how an automorphism acts on $H^1$. For example, let $X$ be the complex torus defined by the lattice $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}i$ and consider $g$ to be multiplication by $i$ (i.e. an elliptic curve with CM). Then,
$$ H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2} $$
and $g$ should act on $H^1$ by swapping the copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.